# Same Step has more than one When/Then

Tags: cucumber, protractor

I am using cucumber with protractor.
Is is possible in Cucumber to have for the same method more than one annotation??

For example something like this:

```
this.Given(/^I log in as user '([^']*)' with password '([^']*)'$/
this.When(/^I log in as user '([^']*)' with password '([^']*)'$/, function(username, password) 
{
}
```

Comment: Does the example you've posted work for you? If not, how does it fail? Thanks.

Comment: if the second annotation was used everything works normally. For the first one I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'timeout' of undefined
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:453:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:382:13)

Comment: Ah, you mean it works in `When` but does not in `Given`? Thanks.

Comment: yes exactly it only works for when

Answer (score 2):

From Cucumbers perspective, there is no difference betwen `Given` and `Then`. The different keywords are there just to enhance the readbility of the `.feature` file. When you implement the steps, you can choose to use any of them.

Personally, I would never consider two different annotations for the same method. One is sufficient. The place where it matters is in the scenario and there I would use whatever I need.

At the same time, I am a but interested in why you describe you system using one `Given` and one `Then` step that actually are the same thing. The `Given` is where you prepare the system under test, the `Then` is where you assert that the expected outcome has occured. It feels surprising to me that they are actually the same execution in your case. Maybe there is a reason, but it seems strange to me at the moment.